# MultivariateNormalDistribution throws "matrix is singular"

Tags: java, random, matrix, apache-commons

I want to generate a random vector with `N(0, C)` distribution, i.e. normal distribution with 0 mean and given covariance matrix `C`.

I'm using [`MultivariateNormalDistribution`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/MultivariateNormalDistribution.html) from Apache Commons:

```
double[] means = new double[2];
double[][] C = {
{ 5.1455479254351755, -2.0050191427617987 },
{ -2.0050191427617987, 0.7812776833676598 } };
new MultivariateNormalDistribution(new JDKRandomGenerator(), means, C);
```

And getting an exception `matrix is singular`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularMatrixException: matrix is singular
    at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.EigenDecomposition$Solver.getInverse(EigenDecomposition.java:533)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.MultivariateNormalDistribution.<init>(MultivariateNormalDistribution.java:125)
    at javabbob.Experiment.main(Experiment.java:52)
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290459/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-matrix-is-singular) that this means, that the matrix is not invertible. Ok.

But, all I want is a random vector with `N(0, C)` distribution. I can use whatever method.

In [Multivariate normal distribution Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) it's written:

> The covariance matrix **is allowed to be singular** (in which case the corresponding distribution has no density). This case arises frequently in statistics (...)

How can I generate such a random vector in Java?

---

I've also tried [`CholeskyDecomposition`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/CholeskyDecomposition.html) with the same `C` array:

```
RealMatrix covMatrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(C);
CholeskyDecomposition choleskyDecomposition = new CholeskyDecomposition(covMatrix);
```

And it also doesn't work, throwing `NonPositiveDefiniteMatrixException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.linear.NonPositiveDefiniteMatrixException: 0 is smaller than, or equal to, the minimum (0): not positive definite matrix: value 0 at index 1
    at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.CholeskyDecomposition.<init>(CholeskyDecomposition.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.CholeskyDecomposition.<init>(CholeskyDecomposition.java:85)
    at javabbob.Experiment.main(Experiment.java:59)
```

---

For people with similar problem:

[Not Positive Definite Matrices - Causes and Cures](http://www2.gsu.edu/~mkteer/npdmatri.html) gave me some insight.

Answer (score 2):

The online matrix calculator at [bluebit.gr](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx) gives the lower triangular Cholesky decomposition of your `C` matrix as:

```
L = { { 2.268380  0.000000},
      {-0.883899  0.000000} };
```

This means you should be able to generate a single standard normal, Z, and transform to obtain your two correlated normals as X<sub>1</sub> = 2.268380*Z and X<sub>2</sub> = -0.883899*Z.  Formally it would be X<sub>2</sub> = -0.883899*Z<sub>1</sub> + 0.000000*Z<sub>2</sub>, but since the lower right entry in the decomposition is zero you don't need a second independent Z.  Add suitable means if they should be non-zero.

**Addendum**

Sorry, I thought you were looking for the solution to this specific problem. In general, decompose the variance/covariance matrix **C** using [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) to get the lower triangular "root" **L**. If **M** is a vector of means and **Z** is a vector of independent normals, then **X** = **M** + **LZ** will be a vector of correlated normals with the desired mean and variance/covariance structure.  I'm not current in Java, so you'll have to find or implement a suitable matrix library. A quick web search showed both [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/CholeskyDecomposition.html) and [NIST](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/CholeskyDecomposition.html) have Cholesky decomposition implementations in Java.

Comment: I think this should work, but Apache library throws `NonPositiveDefiniteMatrixException` and doesn't give L, please check my updated question.

Comment: I tried NIST and it's working! From the docs: *If the matrix is not symmetric or positive definite, the constructor returns a partial decomposition* :) Thank you!